# What is the reading order for Civil War 2?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, marvel-civil-war

What is the ideal reading order for Civil War 2? Different sites show different orders and hence I am confused.

Comment: The best one I've found online is this one; https://marvelguides.com/part-6-civil-war-ii but it's not an 'official' guide. There's also some debate about whether certain issues should be in it at all, but you're not going to miss/spoil anything if you follow this order.